# AS2 Print External image

Tags: actionscript

I have this script where I can print the movie that i indicated in the code.

```
function print_page()
{
    var my_pj = new PrintJob();
    var myResult = my_pj.start();
    if (myResult)
    {
        myResult = my_pj.addPage("img_mc", null, {printAsBitmap:true}, 1);
        my_pj.send();
        delete my_pj;
        trace("ok");
    }
}
```

I need to know, how to print some image that is outside the flahs... clicking in the MC.... but i need in AS2...

ty for help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way i sucess print external image with `PrintJob()` and AS2

```
#include "mc_tween2.as"

_root.myholder.loadMovie("teste_labirinto.jpg");
_root.myholder._x = 0; //i set the x and y position of image out of the screen area!
_root.myholder._y = 990; //

function print_page()
{
    var my_pj = new PrintJob();
    var myResult = my_pj.start();
    if (myResult)
    {
        my_pj.orientation = portrait;
        myResult = my_pj.addPage("myholder", {xMin:0, xMax:600, yMin:0, yMax:800}, {printAsBitmap:true}, 1);
        my_pj.my_pj.send();
        delete my_pj;
        trace("ok");
    }
}

btn.onRelease = function()
{
    print_page();
};
```